# How can I do padding top and bottom of TextField in actionscript3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, padding, textfield

Padding left can be done by TextFormat.leftMargin.
And padding right can be done by TextFormat.rightMargin.

But there is no topMargin or bottomMargin property in TextField or TextFormat.
How can I do padding top and bottom?

Example code of left and right padding(margin) of TextField:

```
var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat
format.leftMargin = 40
format.rightMargin = 40

var text:TextField = new TextField
text.defaultTextFormat = format
text.background = true
text.backgroundColor = 0xeeaaaa
text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER
text.text = 'abc'
```

Comment: Using semicolon is optional, but its a good std. You can use.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add semicolons.
I like to omit semicolons at the end of lines.
But I'm usually trying to add semicolons in my questions at stackoverflow or in programs at work.

Comment: use leading property from TextFormat class
https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html#leading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just increase the height of your sprite, text.height + 10 for example, and set text.y = 5 for a 5 pixel top and bottom margin

Answer (score 2):

You can also add a blank line before and after your text. Combined with the border and background properties of a textField object you can render nice boxes. Code would look like this:

```
var text:TextField = new TextField
text.defaultTextFormat = format
text.background = true
text.backgroundColor = 0xeeaaaa
text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER
text.text = '\n' + 'your text here' + '\n '
```

If you use this solution, do not forget the blank space after the second blank line. It makes sure the blank line is displayed.

Comment: This is a strange world but after reading this great hint I voted up.

Answer (score 1):

There is no predefined option available right now.

But you can `text.y` property instead of `top margin` and `bottom margin`.

```
var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
format.leftMargin = 40;
format.rightMargin = 40;
var text:TextField = new TextField;
text.defaultTextFormat = format;
text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER;
text.text = 'abc\ndef\nhij\nlmno';
var spr:Sprite = new Sprite();
spr.graphics.beginFill(0xeeaaaa,1);
spr.graphics.drawRect(0,0, text.width,text.height);
spr.graphics.endFill();
addChild(spr);
spr.addChild(text);
```

Comment: Thanks!
But text.y just set the position of whole TextField.
I want to increase the area between border of TextField and text of TextField.
Border can be visible by setting properties, `background and backgroundColor or border and borderColor` of TextField.

Comment: you can use sprite or movieClip for setting bgcolor.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's no native way to do it. Here is a list of supported CSS tags (it does not include any padding, nor top or bottom margin):
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6

Comment: That's true. AS3 doesn't have a HTML renderer so you can't expect it to have CSS rendering capabilities. All Flash is really doing is emulating SOME of the CSS properties into text field properties for CONVENIENCE - nothing more. It makes it easier to adapt an existing style guide from a website etc. If you need more advanced rendering (like vertical padding) you need to build the functionality yourself. For example, vertical padding is really just pushing all other content down - you need to build that yourself.